# compiling with tex4ht, how much time is needed?

Tags: tex4ht

I'm tryng to compile my academic thesis in html. I've compiled it with success in pdf, it is about 130 pages full of images and formulas. I want compile it in html to put on my website, i get `xhlatex thesis.tex` and after 70 mins is still compiling. It is normal???

Comment: converting formulas to images can take some time, but 70 minutes seems little bit too much to me

Comment: log doesn't get me error. What alternatives i have?

Comment: have you tried `htlatex myfile.tex "html,mathml"`

Comment: I have a situation with a built that takes more than 10 hours... Still need to look into the problem.

Comment: We need a minimal working example to give an answer here.